# Linq to Sql problem with converting nullable binary format

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am trying to get image from db (SQL server 2008) which are saved as binary nullable value using linq to sql query.
My Query is:

```
var news = from topic in db.PublicNews
orderby topic.PostedDate descending                        
select new PublicNewsDto()
{
     Id = topic.Id,
     PostedDate = topic.PostedDate,
     Summary = topic.Summary,
     Text = topic.Text,
     NewsImg = topic.NewsImg.ToArray()
};
```

I have got `NullReferenceExeption`. If db does not contain null able value that code works properly.

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must first test if topic.NewsImg has a value before assigning it. If it doesn't have a value, pass in a null array, like this:

```
NewsImg = topic.NewsImg.HasValue ? topic.NewsImg.Value.ToArray() : new byte[]
```

EDIT:

The clean way to do it is as follows:

```
var news = from topic in db.PublicNews
            select new PublicNewsDto()
            {
                Id = topic.Id,
                PostedDate = topic.PostedDate,
                Summary = topic.Summary,
                Text = topic.Text,
                NewsImg = (topic.NewsImg.HasValue ? topic.NewsImg.Value : new byte[])
            };

            var orderedNews = news.OrderByDescending(e => e.PostedDate);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I have tried the same code, and it does not work. I have got the next error:

Comment: Could not translate expression 'Table(PublicNew).OrderByDescending(topic => topic.PostedDate).Select(topic => new PublicNewsDto() {Id = .....  Invoke(value(System.Func`1[System.Byte[]])))})' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.

Comment: And remove 'orderby topic.PostedDate descending ' from your expression. It makes no sense to Order your rows if you're creating a list. If yo want your list to be ordered, order it in the end.

Comment: Of course. The structure is the next: public class PublicNewsDto
 {
  public int Id;
  public DateTimeOffset PostedDate;
  public string Text;
  public string Summary;
  public byte[] NewsImg;
 }

Comment: Ok, that is my query. var news = from topic in db.PublicNews
         select new PublicNewsDto()
         {
          Id = topic.Id,
          PostedDate = topic.PostedDate,
          Summary = topic.Summary,
          Text = topic.Text,
          NewsImg = topic.NewsImg != null ? topic.NewsImg.ToArray() : new byte[] { 0 }
         };

Comment: @Hallaghan does not matter if the order by is at the end or in the middle (like his expression) will generate same SQL

Comment: @Magnus I asked him to remove the order by from the query because he doesn't need to order his records while creating the list. He can order them later into another variable with as many conditions as he wants. It's just to keep it clean.

Comment: No it does not work. I have got the same error :( Could not translate expression..........

Comment: When you try writing .HasValue, does intellisense bring that up for you?